# Download an SSRS report in Python using requests

Tags: python, reporting-services, python-requests

I am trying to use `requests` to download an SSRS report. The following code will download an empty Excel file:

```
url = 'http://MY REPORT URL HERE/ReportServer?/REPORT NAME HERE&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML'

s = requests.Session()
s.post(url, data={'_username': 'username, '_password': 'password'})

r = s.get(url)

output_file = r'C:\Saved Reports\File.xlsx'

downloaded_file = open(output_file, 'wb')
for chunk in r.iter_content(100000):
    downloaded_file.write(chunk)
```

I have successfully used `requests_ntlm` to complete this task, but I am wondering why the above code is not working as intended. The Excel file turns out to be empty; I feel it is due to an issue with logging in and passing those cookies to the `GET` request.

Comment: Try passing URL into browser and see the behavior, does it ask you for Login? Does the url get you to correct report.
May be try url without format and see what results you get

Comment: When a user navigates to the URL, the report begins downloading. I've tried the report URL, as well as only the URL of the report server. Both produce empty Excel files.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work, but for pdfs. I found the solution [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/67xak4/enterprise_intranet_authentication_and_ssrs/.)

Here's a piece of my code snippet:

```
import requests
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

session = requests.Session()
session.auth = HttpNtlmAuth(domain+uid,pwd)
response = session.get(reporturl,stream=True)
print response.status_code
with open(outputlocation+mdcProp+'.pdf','wb') as pdf:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            pdf.write(chunk)
session.close()
```